# Disabling OCR when uploading to Google Drive via API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I was running into an issue with unconv where it would periodically just hang indefinitely when trying to convert random documents to PDFs, so I wrote a small python script to upload documents to GDrive and download them again as PDFs to work around this issue.

The problem I've run into is that, google drive is automatically trying to OCR images that get uploaded and I don't want that to happen, but I've thus far been unable to find documentation on how to disable the OCR.

One thing I did notice: I'm the [create function from v3 of the api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), in the v2 api, there is an [insert function](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) that takes an OCR flag. Is this possible with the v3 api?

Here is my code:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import httplib2
    import magic
    import io
    import sys
    import argparse
    import subprocess as sp

    from apiclient import discovery
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    from httplib2 import Http

    from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
    from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

    from settings import *

    """
    This script exists to mask unoconv for JUST pdf conversion. If it gets flags for anything else, it will fallback on unoconv.

    Otherwise, it uploads the document to google drive, download it as a pdf, and then delete the file out of the drive.
    """

    MIMETYPE_MAPPING = {
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "application/rtf":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "text/richtext":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "text/plain":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "text/html":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "application/msword":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",

        "application/vnd.ms-excel":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheets",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheets",
        "text/csv":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheets",
        "text/tab-separated-values":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheets",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheets":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheets",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheets",

        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint":"application/vnd.google-apps.presentation",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentationml":"application/vnd.google-apps.presentation",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation":"application/vnd.google-apps.presentation",

        "image/png":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "image/x-citrix-png":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "image/x-png":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "image/jpeg":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "image/x-citrix-jpeg":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "image/gif":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "image/bmp":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",

        "application/pdf":"application/vnd.google-apps.document",
    }

    SERVICE = None

    def get_service():
        """
        Establishes the connection to the google drive APIs.
        """
        global SERVICE
        if SERVICE is None:
            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json(JSON_KEY)
            http = http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
            SERVICE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)
        return SERVICE

    def drive_upload(fp, fn):
        """
        Uploads the file found at fp to root of google drive account as a google doc with name fn

        Returns the id of the new file
        """
        mimetype = magic.from_file(fp, mime=True)
        drive_service = get_service()
        file_metadata = {
            'name' : fn,
            'mimeType' : MIMETYPE_MAPPING.get(mimetype, 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'),
        } 
        media = MediaFileUpload(fp,
                                mimetype=mimetype,
                                resumable=True)
        import inspect
        print(inspect.getargspec(drive_service.files().create)[0])

        file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                            media_body=media,
                                            fields='id').execute()
        return file.get('id')

    def download_pdf(file_id,dlp):
        """
        Downloads file from google drive specified by file_id to the filepath in dlp

        Will download file as pdf
        """
        drive_service = get_service()
        request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                                     mimeType='application/pdf')
        resp = request.execute()
        f = open(dlp,'w')
        f.write(resp)
        f.close()

    def convert_to_pdf(inputf, outputf):
        """
        Converts input file to pdf located at output file and cleans up file from google drive
        """
        fid = drive_upload(inputf,inputf.split('/')[-1])
        download_pdf(fid,outputf)

        #Now delete the file from drive
        service = get_service()
        service.files().delete(fileId=fid).execute()

    def pass_through():
        """
        Calls unoconv with same args that were passed to this script
        """
        print("PASSING THROUGH",file=sys.stderr)
        cmd = PATH_TO_UNOCONV + " " + " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
        child = sp.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = child.communicate()

        print(stdout,end='')
        print(stderr, file=sys.stderr,end='')
        sys.exit(child.returncode)

    class ArgParse(argparse.ArgumentParser):
        """
        This subclass of ArgumentParser exists to change the default behaviour of the exit function

        If the exit function is called with a status other than 0 (usually because unsupported flags are used),
            a call is made to pass_through let unoconv handle this call.
        """

        def exit(self, status=0,message=None):
            if status != 0:
                pass_through()
            else:
                return super(ArgParse,self).exit(status=status,message=message)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = ArgParse(description="Wrapper for unoconv that farms pdf conversions to google drive, using any args other than the supplied will cause it to fallback on unoconv")
        parser.add_argument('-f', metavar='format', help='Desired ouput format')
        parser.add_argument('-o', metavar='output_file',  help='Path to output file')
        parser.add_argument('fname', metavar='inputf', type=str, nargs=1, help='Path to file to convert')

        args = parser.parse_args()

        fmt = args.f
        output_file = args.o
        input_file = args.fname[0]

        if fmt.upper() == "PDF":
            try:
                convert_to_pdf(input_file, output_file)
            except:
                pass_through()
        else:
            #if we aren't converting the file to a PDF, let unoconv handle it
            pass_through()
```

Comment: Can I ask you about what you want to do? You want to upload an image to Google Drive and convert to PDF, and then download it as a PDF. When the image is converted to PDF, you don't want to convert by OCR. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: In "Migrate to Google Drive API v3", they say ``OCR is enabled automatically for image imports``. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/migration So after an image file are uploaded as the image, it imports the image to Document using GAS. And then, download the Document as a PDF file. I think that you can achieve this using Web Apps. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.